# Match nodes with same name present at any level

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<xml>
  <start>
    <p>Welcome</p>
    <figure>
      <graphic name="abc.svg"></graphic>      
    </figure>
    <chapter>
      <p>Sample text</p>
      <figure>
        <graphic name="one.svg"></graphic>       
      </figure>
      <chapter>
         <figure>
           <graphic name="two.svg"></graphic>       
         </figure>
         <p>Hello World</p>
      </chapter>
      <chapter>
          <p>Life is good</p>
         <figure>
           <graphic name="three.svg"></graphic>       
         </figure>            
      </chapter>
    </chapter>
  </start>
</xml>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 Welcome
abc.svg
Sample Text
one.svg
two.svg
Hello World
Life is good
three.svg
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$context[name() = 'CHAPTER']" mode="chapter" />

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="chapter">
    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
        <fo:block margin-left="1mm">                
            <xsl:if test="name(./following-sibling::*) = 'figure'">             
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[name() = 'FIGURE']" mode="figure" 
                    /> 
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="node()[name() = 'figure']" mode="figure">               
    <xsl:variable name="ImageName">
        <xsl:value-of
            select="current()/L-GRAPHIC/GRAPHIC/@FILENAME" />
    </xsl:variable>     
    <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic>
            <xsl:attribute name="src"> <xsl:value-of
                select="concat('../resources/', 
    $ImageName)" /> </xsl:attribute>
        </fo:external-graphic>
    </fo:block>     
</xsl:template>
```

**Problem:**
WIth the above xslt(XPath) I am getting the following output:

```
Welcome
abc.svg
Sample Text
one.svg
Hello World
Life is good
```

The innermost nested figure elements **two.svg and three.svg are not appearing in the output**. But the text is coming from any level. I have a dtd file which has defined that within the chapter element there can be figure element any where. But the order of elements is not known.
So I am making a check that if it has a figure element, then display it.
I want XSL FO output in pdf format.
There is something more needed in the XPath expression name(./following-sibling::*) = 'figure'. I am not getting it.
Please help me.

Other solutions tried:

```
<xsl:if test="current()[name() = 'figure']"></xsl:if>
```

But Only first figure, abc.svg appears.
Thank you.

Comment: If you "want XSL FO output" then please show actual XSL-FO code as output - any textual approximation does not help much. Also, your XSLT stylesheet is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general pattern you need to follow is this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//figure" />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="figure">
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::p"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="graphic/@name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::p"/>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you need to "decorate" the paragraphs (I use a HTML list, but you can sprinkle your FO in there), then you need conditional formatting, use this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <ol>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//figure" />
            </ol>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="figure">
            <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::p">
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::p" />
                </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="graphic/@name" />
            </li>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::p">
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::p" />
                </li>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope that helps. XSLT works best when you name things, not go after node() unless you have to